# AWS Boto3 SDK Access Analyzer list_findings Input Argument Error

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to use the AWS boto3 Python sdk to work with the Access Analyzer api. Specifically the list_findings action. The relevant api documentation is here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/access-analyzer/latest/APIReference/API_ListFindings.html
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/accessanalyzer.html#AccessAnalyzer.Client.list_findings

According to the documentation the input parameters to this action includes

```
"sort": { 
    "attributeName": "string",
    "orderBy": "string"
}
```

The documentation, as far as I can tell, doesn't place any restrictions on what the `attributeName` can be and therefore it seems that any valid field on the returned findings should be valid input.  The structure of the returned findings is described as

```
{
   "findings": [ 
      { 
         "action": [ "string" ],
         "analyzedAt": number,
         "condition": { 
            "string" : "string" 
         },
         "createdAt": number,
         "error": "string",
         "id": "string",
         "isPublic": boolean,
         "principal": { 
            "string" : "string" 
         },
         "resource": "string",
         "resourceOwnerAccount": "string",
         "resourceType": "string",
         "sources": [ 
            { 
               "detail": { 
                  "accessPointArn": "string"
               },
               "type": "string"
            }
         ],
         "status": "string",
         "updatedAt": number
      }
   ],
   "nextToken": "string"
}
```

I would like to sort by the `createdAt` attribute on the returned findings.  For all the fields I have tried they always return the same error

```
Error has occured in AWS Access Analyzer Integration: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ListFindings operation: Invalid sort.attributeName
```

An example piece of code I am trying is as follows

```
client = aws_session(
        region='region',
        roleArn='roleArn',
        roleSessionName='roleSessionName',
        roleSessionDuration='roleSessionDuration',
    )

    kwargs = {
        'analyzerArn': 'some_ARN_here'
    }

    kwargs['sort'] = {
        'attributeName': 'createdAt',
        'orderBy': 'ASC'
    }

    response = client.list_findings(**kwargs)
```

Without the `sort` arguement the code behaves as expected and returns results.  No matter what attribute I use in the sort field it always returns the same error.

How do I know what the valid `attributeName`'s are? What is the correct format for passing parameters in this case? I have not been able to find any other examples online using this particular portion of the boto3 sdk.  Any insight would be appreciated.

I am looking to sort the findings in order to retrieve only the most recent. By default the oldest is returned first when specifying `maxResults` as an arguement.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, and hopefully this saves someone a months time, is that this is not documented correctly anywhere.  I had to use my browsers inspector to see the params passed in the request when performing some actions in the AWS UI for Access Analyzer and noticed they were passing `UpdatedAt` in the `attributeName` for the sort field.

This subtle distinction was breaking the API call as the `U` needs to be capitalized in `updatedAt` when being passed as a parameter.  Where is this is documented? Seems nowhere.  Not all the fields on findings worked as a sort attribute, such as `createdAt`. So in order to use the sort field you need to format as such on list_findings

```
kwargs['sort'] = {
    'attributeName': 'UpdatedAt',
    'orderBy': 'ASC'
}
```

This is not representative of how the fields are returned from the API and is not intuitive.  The way the parameters are passed to the API are not in the same format as they are received.